# Python Flask- Am I doing something wrong with Flash messages?

Tags: python, flask

My flash messages are not working and I'm not sure why. Maybe it's something to do with my bootstrap? Help is very much so appreciated. Thank you.

Example of How I am using them in Flask:

```
flash("You are not logged in!", "danger")
return redirect(url_for("accounts.login"))
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mysite</title>
    <!-- meta -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <!-- styles -->
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename="styles.css")}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    {% block css %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>

    {% include "navigation.html" %}

    <div class="container">

      <br>

      <!-- messages -->
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
      {% if messages %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {% for category, message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
           {{message}}
           <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}

      <!-- child template -->
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    </div>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block js %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

login.html:

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
      <form role="form" method="post" action="">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal text-center">Login to your account</h1><br>

        <div class="form-floating">
          {{ form.email(arialabel="email", class="form-control mb-3", style="height: 50px;") }}
          {{ form.email.label }}
            {% if form.email.errors %}
              {% for error in form.email.errors %}
              <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                {{ error }}
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          {{ form.password(arialabel="password", class="form-control mb-3", style="height: 50px;") }}
          {{ form.password.label }}
            {% if form.password.errors %}
              {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {{ error }}
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="text-center mt-3"><a href="{{ url_for('accounts.reset_password') }}">Forgot password?</a></p>
        <p class="text-center mt-3">New User? <a href="{{ url_for('accounts.register') }}">Register now</a></p>
      </form>
    </main>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Help is very appreciated as I'm not really sure what is going wrong here, could it be a bootstrap issue?

, Thank you.

Comment: Are you have a SECRET_KEY variable and a TEMPLATE_FILE variable?